# Can't Use --login-path to Login on Mac

Tags: mysql, authentication, path, config

My MySQL version is 5.7.13 and Mac is 10.11.16. I tried to login to the database using MySQL Config Editor in terminal.

I set up the client info and using below command to login.

```
mysql --login-path=localuser
```

Somehow, the terminal gave me this error...

```
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'login-path=localuser'
```

Is there any possible way to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: The same problem!
I wasted a few hours until I understood that I'm connecting to the same host...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing **mysql-config-editor**
Also once you have it installed you need to configure login path, with command simillar to this:

`mysql_config_editor set --login-path=storedPasswordKey --host=localhost --user=root --password`

May be you didn't install correctly mysql.
Try using installing it from the official source : 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html

Or may be you didn't install Mysql Utilities correctly.
Try installing them from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities .

Also on debian based system  can do:

`apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

According to this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73670 , the issue you are experiencing is a known bug for debian, I hope the steps above can resolve your issue, Also more details on this subject you can find on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html

If you are certain that you have installed all the tools correctly and it still doesn't work try submiting a bug to http://bugs.mysql.com/

Comment: Thanks for the respond! I l already have set up mysql-config-editor. I even run this command, mysql_config_editor print --all, and the result is correct! Do you have any possible way to solve this issue? Thank you so much!

Comment: try installing the utilities from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, still the answer might help others:

I had the same problem on my mac (can't tell if it's a specific mac problem though). Turns out I also had `-h hostname` on my command line, and that seems to be redundant with `--login-path`. Removing the `-h` option fixed it.

HTH